# c why does this print a negative number?

Tags: c, hex

I was expecting this to print a very large number and that same number -1 but it just prints -1 and -2, why is this?

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", 0xffffffff);
fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", 0xfffffffe);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `%d` format is a signed integer (decimal). Integers are stored using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which means that the high-order bit (8000 0000) indicates, in a manner of speaking, the sign of the value.

Counting down from 3, values are:

```
0000 0003 = 3
0000 0002 = 2
0000 0001 = 1
0000 0000 = 0
FFFF FFFF = -1
FFFF FFFE = -2
```

etc.

If you want FFFF FFFF to display as a large positive number, use the `%u` (unsigned) format.

Comment: oh, whats the % for long? or unsigned?

Comment: %u - just added to the response :)

Comment: int is %d, unsigned is %u, long int is %ld, long unsigned is %lu

Comment: no, the %d means signed decimal, a %u would be unsigned decimal.

Comment: the % just indicates that "something" is going to get put there.  For example %.02f is perfectly legit and will print a floating point with 2 digits after the decimal point and if there are no post decimal point digits will print 2 0s.

Comment: The C standard doesn't mandate that integers should be stored in 2's complement representation. It's left to the implementation to decide among the three possible representations
and a conforming implementation can use *sign & magnitude* in which case there can be a possible value *negative zero* which is not possible in 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 8):

The argument "%d" prints the input as a signed integer. As a result, you have discovered the [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s%5Fcomplement), consider "%u" instead.

Answer (score 4):

The values you mention are the two's complement representation of -1 and -2

Look up [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 3):

The first bit on a signed integer is the sign, so the highest number that could be stored is 0xEFFFFFFF.